# need to deny a pipeline made from a specified branch merge

Tags: regex, linux, git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I need help.

I have 3 branches

- master
- hotfix
- feature

I want the build to occur only on the master coming from merge with the feature. How could I do this?

I am allowing the build to occur in jenkins if it comes from a merge to master made with the feature, as I will run another pipeline in the hotfix and I want it when the hotfix merge with the master nothing happens.

My regular expression today is

[image: regex]

but I'm refusing everything from the master, in case I want to allow the master to execute just coming from a merge with the feature branch

I thought of another option too, I can release the pipeline in the master coming from merge with any branch, only when it comes from the hotfix branch.

If in the future I have more branches and want to run the pipeline to the merge with the master

Comment: Can  you add some example which branches should and should not be matched?

Comment: Let me cite an example:




I have 5 Branches: 

"dev"
"release"
"feature"
"master"
"hotfix"


, I already have a pipeline in jenkins configured and every time my developers work in a branch and make the merge to the master a pipeline in the master occurs.

,I wanted it to happen in the master pipeline always the same way ... more when a merge was made from the branch release it was not denied and did not activate my pipeline